# Из типа char * в тип int *

Tags: c++

Из-за невозможности неявного преобразования из типа char * в тип int * в проекте при компиляции происходит ошибка:

> ...\ProcMem.cpp   In file included from ProcMem.cpp
>   ...\ProcMem.h In member function 'cData ProcMem::Read(DWORD, char*, BOOL)':
>   ...\ProcMem.h [Error] no matching function for call to 'ProcMem::iSizeOfArray(char*&)'
>   ...\ProcMem.h [Note] candidate is:
>   ...\ProcMem.cpp   In file included from ProcMem.cpp
>   ...\ProcMem.h [Note] int ProcMem::iSizeOfArray(int*)
>   ...\ProcMem.h [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char*' to 'int*'

Что мне нужно изменить в ProcMem.h?

```
#ifndef PROCMEM_H //If Not Defined
#define PROCMEM_H //Define Now

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN //Excludes Headers We Wont Use (Increase Compile Time)

#include <assert.h>
#include <windows.h> //Standard Windows Functions/Data Types
#include <iostream> //Constains Input/Output Functions (cin/cout etc..)
#include <TlHelp32.h> //Contains Read/Write Functions
#include <string> //Support For Strings
#include <sstream> //Supports Data Conversion

using namespace std;

class ProcMem{
protected:

//STORAGE
HANDLE hProcess;
DWORD dwPID, dwProtection, dwCaveAddress;

//MISC
BOOL bPOn, bIOn, bProt;

public:

//MISC FUNCTIONS
ProcMem();
~ProcMem();
int chSizeOfArray(char *chArray); //Return Size Of External Char Array
int iSizeOfArray(int *iArray); //Return Size Of External Int Array
bool iFind(int *iAry, int iVal); //Return Boolean Value To Find A Value Inside An Int Array

#pragma region TEMPLATE MEMORY FUNCTIONS

//REMOVE READ/WRITE PROTECTION
template <class cData>
void Protection(DWORD dwAddress)
{
    if (!bProt)
        VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, sizeof(cData), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtection); //Remove Read/Write Protection By Giving It New Permissions
    else
        VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, sizeof(cData), dwProtection, &dwProtection); //Restore The Old Permissions After You Have Red The dwAddress

    bProt = !bProt;
}

//READ MEMORY 
template <class cData>
cData Read(DWORD dwAddress)
{
    cData cRead; //Generic Variable To Store Data
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, &cRead, sizeof(cData), NULL); //Win API - Reads Data At Specified Location 
    return cRead; //Returns Value At Specified dwAddress
}

//READ MEMORY - Pointer
template <class cData>
cData Read(DWORD dwAddress, char *Offset, BOOL Type)
{
    //Variables
    int iSize = iSizeOfArray(Offset) - 1; //Size Of *Array Of Offsets 
    dwAddress = Read<DWORD>(dwAddress); //HEX VAL

    //Loop Through Each Offset & Store Hex Value (Address)
    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
        dwAddress = Read<DWORD>(dwAddress + Offset[i]);

    if (!Type)
        return dwAddress + Offset[iSize]; //FALSE - Return Address
    else
        return Read<cData>(dwAddress + Offset[iSize]); //TRUE - Return Value
}

// WRITE MEMORY
template <class cData>
void Write(DWORD dwAddress, cData Value)
{
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, &Value, sizeof(cData), NULL);
}

// WRITE MEMORY - Pointer
template <class cData>
void Write(DWORD dwAddress, char *Offset, cData Value)
{
    Write<cData>(Read<cData>(dwAddress, Offset, false), Value);
}

// Base read
template <typename TYPE>
TYPE RPM(LPVOID lpBaseAddress, SIZE_T nSize)
{
    TYPE data = TYPE();
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, &data, nSize, NULL);
    return data;
}

// Base write
void WPM(LPVOID lpBaseAddress, LPCVOID lpBuffer, SIZE_T nSize)
{
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, lpBuffer, nSize, NULL);
}

// MEMORY FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
virtual bool Process(char* ProcessName); // Return Handle To The Process
virtual void Patch(DWORD dwAddress, char *chPatch_Bts, char *chDefault_Bts); // Write Bytes To Specified Address
virtual void Inject(DWORD dwAddress, char *chInj_Bts, char *chDef_Bts, BOOL Type); // Jump To A Codecave And Write Memory
virtual DWORD AOB_Scan(DWORD dwAddress, DWORD dwEnd, char *chPattern); // Find A Byte Pattern
virtual bool Module(LPSTR ModuleName, DWORD &output); // Return Module Base Address

#pragma endregion   

};
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать приведение типов `reinterpret_cast` при условии, что значение исходного указателя типа `char *` соответственно выравнено на границу для типа int.

Например,

```
int a[10];

char *cp = reinterpret_cast<char *>( a );
int  *ip = reinterpret_cast<int *>( cp );
```

Но я думаю, что ваш вопрос к вашей проблеме не имеет отношения. Скорей всего вы по недопониманию пытаетесь сделать что-то некорректное либо в проектировании ваших классов, либо в обращении с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно понимать в каком контексте вызывается вот эта функция:

```
//READ MEMORY - Pointer
template <class cData>
cData Read(DWORD dwAddress, char *Offset, BOOL Type)
{
    //Variables
    int iSize = iSizeOfArray(Offset) - 1; //Size Of *Array Of Offsets
```

Если туда действительно передаётся указатель на `char *`, то и вызывать далее нужно не `iSizeOfArray()`, а `chSizeOfArray()`.

Или же наоборот, в эту функцию по архитектуре задачи нужно передавать `int *`, тогда вызов `iSizeOfArray()` верен, а вот прототип `Read()` - нет.

Точней вам может ответить только тот человек, который проектировал весь этот функционал. И/или тот, у которого есть хорошее его понимание плюс полный набор исходников перед глазами.

Comment: Дело в том, что если я меняю iSizeOfArray() на chSizeOfArray(), то появляется ошибка ...\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status. Хотя файла collect2 в указанной директории нету. А если заменить cData Read(DWORD dwAddress, char *Offset, BOOL Type) на int *Offset то начинается каша в сообщениях от компилятора, с разными предупреждниями и ошибкой

Comment: А вы не меняйте вслепую, попробуйте подумать: что этот код должен делать и какой вызов тут будет правильней. Не надо пытаться программировать "методом случайного тыка". И уж тем более нам тут телепатически сложно догадаться как именно должен работать **ваш** код. `ld returned 1 exit status` -- и? Наверняка там есть ещё какие-то слова, которые нужно прочитать и осмыслить. Например (это уже догадки) про то, что "symbol chSizeOfArray undefined".

Comment: Решение этой проблемы важно в первую очередь для меня, соответственно я бы не стал упускать такие детали. Но в том-то и дело, что Error: ld returned 1 exit - это вся информация о моей ошибке, никакого продолжения там нету. И ошибка ссылается на выше упомянутый collect2.exe, которого по указанному пути нету